# Insert Record Else Update From Select Query MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use update if not exists in this query?

```
INSERT INTO MyTbl(name, address, tele)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT name FROM MyTblWHERE name = 'Rupert'
) LIMIT 1;
```

I tried this but this throws error.

```
INSERT INTO MyTbl(name, address, tele)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT name FROM MyTblWHERE name = 'Rupert'
) LIMIT 1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = tmp.Name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need column names in the subquery:

```
INSERT INTO MyTbl (name, address, tele)
    SELECT name, address, tele
    FROM (SELECT 'Rupert' as name, 'Somewhere' as address, '022' as tele
         ) t
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = t.Name;
```

You don't need the `EXISTS` check -- presumably you have a unique constraint if you are using `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.  If you don't have a unique key, then presumably you want:

```
create index unq_mytbl_name on mytbl(name);
```

Similarly, the `LIMIT 1` is irrelevant:  your data has only one row.

For a single row, you might find it more convenient to write this as:

```
INSERT INTO MyTbl (name, address, tele)
    VALUES ('Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(Name);
```

Comment: I am actually inserting data based on Name that's why there is the filter in where clause, Will you solution work exactly excluding "where"?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI . . . If you do not want duplicate names, then you want a unique index (or constraint) on `name`.  Then all the queries in this answer do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use Like this    

INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
    name="A", age=19
```

Answer (score 1):

As nobody knows your table structure or how your data is stored and real data requirements/constraints maybe the best way to **simulate** more or less the ANSI/ISO SQL standard `MERGE` (upsert) command with the querys below..

```
UPDATE
  MyTbl
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT
        MyTbl.id
   FROM MyTbl
   WHERE
     MyTbl.name = 'Rupert'
    AND
     MyTbl.address = 'Somewhere'
   AND
    MyTbl.tele = '022' 
) AS MyTbl_checked
USING(id) # assumes a PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT id
SET
    MyTbl.name = 'Rupert'
  , MyTbl.address = 'Somewhere'
  , MyTbl.tele = '022'
WHERE
   MyTbl.id = MyTbl_checked.id; 

INSERT INTO MyTbl(name, address, tele)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM MyTblWHERE name = 'Rupert'
);
```

**Note:** 
 
Untested but in theory it should do the trick just fine. 
Also these queries will not correctly handle cases where people sharing the same name on address/tele combination, so keep that in mind.

**Performance note** 
For performance a normal key can be created and need to atleast be `KEY(name, address, tele)` to boost both the INSERT and UPDATE.

As MySQL dialect implemention of `MERGE` (upsert) requires a unique key on name when using the query below..

```
INSERT INTO MyTbl (name, address, tele)
    SELECT name, address, tele
    FROM (SELECT 'Rupert' as name, 'Somewhere' as address, '022' as tele
         ) t
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = t.Name;
```

Meaning it will limit the usage of `Rupert` to be used only once..